# Does calling Debug.Log in Application.logMessageReceived callback cause recursion?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logging

I'm wondering if this code causes recursion or not:

```
using UnityEngine;

void Awake()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived += callback;
}

void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Start");
}

void callback(string condition, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    Debug.Log("Hello world");
}
```

I think the log inside the callback will cause the callback to be called again. Is this correct?

Comment: yes, why would you do that? and .. isn't this something you can simply test on your own? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code as given will cause recursion. Calls to any of the logging functions (`Debug.Log`,`Debug.LogWarning`,`Debug.LogError`,etc.) will result in `logMessageReceived` being triggered.

Of course this is also the case for Monobehaviour's `print` function, which is identical to `Debug.Log`.

As such, using the standard log functions inside your callback routine will once again cause `logMessageReceived` to be triggered.

Answer (score -1):

The provided code does not contain a recursive function or induce recursion.

A recursive function refers to a function that calls itself within its own execution. In the given code, there is a callback function, but it is registered as a callback for the "Application.logMessageReceived" event in the Awake method. Essentially, the callback function will be invoked whenever a log message is generated in Unity.

Inside the callback function, Debug.Log("Hello world") is called, but it simply outputs "Hello world" to the Unity console. There is no recursive call or recursive structure involved.

Comment: Are you saying that Debug.Log("Hello world") does not call the logMessageReceived event?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in my previous response. You are correct. Debug.Log("Hello world") statement in the callback function indirectly triggers the logMessageReceived event.
Thus, when the Debug.Log("Hello world") statement is executed within the callback function, it will trigger the logMessageReceived event again, leading to an infinite loop of log messages saying "Hello world". Therefore, the provided code contains an unintended recursion.